# Settings to upload large file via WinRM and Copy-Item - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I´m trying to copy a large file (around 180MB) to a remote server using PowerShell Copy-Item.

```
Copy-Item –Path "$sourcePath" –Destination "$destPath" -Force –ToSession $session
```

It works for files of arround 100MB, but i'm having issues with larger files.

The error is:

```
The runspace state is not valid for this operation.
```

And my config is:

```
Config
    MaxEnvelopeSizekb = 256000
    MaxTimeoutms = 60000
    MaxBatchItems = 32000
    MaxProviderRequests = 4294967295
    Client
        NetworkDelayms = 5000
        URLPrefix = wsman
        AllowUnencrypted = true
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Digest = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = true
            CredSSP = false
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
```

Comment: i would use either `robocopy` OR the BITS commands. both are generally better for large files.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the MaxEnvelopeSize is the same on your source and destination server.

```
$ses = new-pssession $destServerName
Invoke-Command -Session $ses -ScriptBlock {  get-WSManInstance -ResourceURI winrm/config | Select-Object MaxEnvelopeSizekb }
```

Your output will look something like this

```
MaxEnvelopeSizekb PSComputerName RunspaceId
----------------- -------------- ----------
4608              destServerName    b135b977-1f1e-4eef-a5e0-75e94109aa2f
```

Compare that with the MaxEnvolopeSize on your source machine.

```
get-WSManInstance -ResourceURI winrm/config | Select-Object MaxEnvelopeSizekb
```

In the case of the poster, the output will look like

```
MaxEnvelopeSizekb
-----------------
256000
```

You will want these to be the same. So changing the destination server is 1 option.

```
Invoke-Command -Session $ses -ScriptBlock {  set-WSManInstance -ResourceURI winrm/config -ValueSet @{MaxEnvelopeSizekb = "256000" }}
```

Of course, you could change the source or both, it doesn't matter so long as they match.

but then the `copy-item` command with `--tosession` will work

```
Copy-Item –Path $sourcePath –Destination $destPath -Force –ToSession $ses
```